# pseudo transparency window background in python

Tags: python, background, transparency, pygtk, cairo

How do you add pseudo transparent backgrounds to a window using pygtk and cairo? I plan to use it to get semi transparent background in a dock for users who doesn't use composite managers.

Edit: Looking in virtual terminal source, I guess I should use root window pixmap, but how do I do that in python?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can load wallpaper into a Pixbuf, and then create a subpixbuf from it and draw it with cairo in the window.

You can load the current wallpaper using GLib.Settings.

In vala (don't know pygtk, but it's very similar) it would be something like this:

```
GLib.Settings settings = new GLib.Settings ("org.gnome.desktop.background");
```

and then use get_string() to get the picture path.

Comment: That will only work in gnome, not if the user uses any other DE, right?